# TexStudio autocompletes when I type braces

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

When I try to type something in texstudio that has a macro associated, such as `\hl{}` it actually autocompletes to `\hline{}` as soon as I type the brace (it also does this for brackets). Words don't autocomplete when I type a space or when I hit escape.  However, it's super annoying to have to hit escape every time I type a function that might autocomplete on me.

I know that part of the problem is that new commands aren't in the Texstudio autocomplete list, but I feel like typing a brace should override autocomplete in any case.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: press `ESC` when the \hline pops up.

Comment: In general, new commands are in the autocomplete list. Where and how did you define it?

Comment: Thanks.  I'd already figured out `ESC`, but it's an annoying extra stroke that isn't needed on all words. The new commands were defined in an associated .sty file that I've created myself.  I know how to add `\hl` to the autocomplete by configuring it to use `color`, however, it's still not including my own packages.  Since this is a potential problem, I'd still prefer to have autocomplete end as-is when I type anything that is (a) not a letter, (b) not tab. Tab autocomplete is nice. Brace autocomplete is not nice.

Answer (score 5):

**Uncheck** the option (make sure advanced options is toggled):

```
Configure TeXstudio -> Completion -> Complete selected text when non-word character is pressed
```

[image]

then `\hl{` will no longer autocomplete to `\hline{}`.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for my entire life. I would have upvoted more than 1 time if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called "soul.cwl" file with the contents

```
\hl
```

in the config directory. This is normally placed in ~/.config/texstudio under linux and usually "c:\Documents and Settings/User/AppData/Roaming/texstudio" in windows.

This it will see hl as a command to autocomplete to. See also the [helpfile for texstudio.](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION040)